# Fortran OOP Generic

Tags: oop, fortran, generic-programming

I am getting confused on the difference between using

```
Procedure :: momentum => particle_momentum
```

and using

```
Procedure :: particle_momentum 
generic :: momentum => particle_momentum
```

Here is a type declaration

```
type particle

  type(vector) :: position, velocity
  real :: mass

  contains

  procedure :: momentum => particle_momentum
  procedure :: energy => particle_energy

end type particle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Procedure :: momentum => particle_momentum`

defines a *type-bound procedure*, similar to virtual procedures in other languages. It is a binding of an existing procedure to perform the role of the type-bound procedure.

They use the *[dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)*, i.e., when you call

```
  class(particle) :: o
  ..
  call o%momentum
```

it is possible that if the dynamic type of `o` is en extended type (child) of `particle` you actually run a procedure that overrides `particle_momentum`. You don't know if you actually call the original, or the overriding procedure, until run-time.

Now suppose you have

```
procedure :: particle_momentum_int
procedure :: particle_momentum_real
generic :: momentum => particle_momentum_int, particle_momentum_real
```

as

```
subroutine particle_momentum_real(self, a)
   class(particle) :: self
   real :: a

subroutine particle_momentum_int(self, a)
   class(particle) :: self
   integer :: a
```

Then if you call

```
class(particle) :: o !or just type(o)
..
call o%momentum(1)
```

you know that you call the `_int` variant by the rules of generic disambiguation and you know it at the compile-time. This is the *static dispatch*.

Answer (score 0):

Simply saying, "generic" is to make life easier, the compiler chooses the suitable form of a procedure among others just by calling a specific command, for example, you want to call the right constructor of an object with "initialize" command. There are some rules should be obeyed the compiler can distinguish them.

On the other hand, "procedure:: x=>y" is employed to override/point one of object procedures (x) to a new function (y).